# Clojure csv to map like {:key1 #{a, b, c}, :key2 #{n, m, k}}

Tags: clojure

After loading :

```
(csv/read-csv "Fetch, get, bring \n  Take, receive, accept")
```

I get :

```
(["Fetch" " get" " bring "] ["  Take" " receive" " accept"])
```

Now, I want to turn it into a map with unique keys and sets as values like:

```
[:key1 #{Fetch, get, bring}, :key2 #{Take, receive, accept}]
```

My goal is to be able to look up a word, say get, and return "Fetch, bring"

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Im thinking in the lines of :   user=> (doseq [i inm]
                                             #_=> (let [x (gensym ":key")]
                                             #_=> (assoc hm x i))
                                             #_=> (prn hm))

Comment: Why do you pack the things you want to look up in the values of the map?

Comment: @cfrick I ended up using sets instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to be able to look up a word, say get, and return "Fetch, bring"

Not completely sure about your goal, but that did not stop me from implementing a function that gets all siblings of a word. I don't think you need a map with random keys, or do you? Note that a set is implemented as a hash-map where the values are the same as the keys (e.g., `#{:a :b}` is a wrapping around `{:a :a, :b :b}`).

Now, first parse the data to a list of words-sets:

```
(def word-sets
  (map (comp set #(map string/trim %))
       (csv/read-csv "Fetch, get, bring \n  Take, receive, accept")))
;; => (#{"bring" "Fetch" "get"} #{"accept" "Take" "receive"})
```

Then the function to get the siblings of a word:

```
(defn siblings [word]
  (mapcat #(when (contains? % word) (disj % word))
          word-sets))
```

Using the set operator `contains?` we check every word-set if it contains the word, if so we return that set with that word `disj`oined. Because of the `when`, a word-set that does not contain the word becomes `nil` and `mapcat` removes the `nil` entries and concats the rest to one flat list.

E.g.,

```
(siblings "get")
;; => ("bring" "fetch")

(siblings "Take")
;; => ("accept" "receive")

(siblings "non existing")
;; => '()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate it.! I did end up using a set, but for completion I just added an answer that gives us something close to what I started off with.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get something similar, does the trick for me.

inp being (["Fetch" " get" " bring "] ["  Take" " receive" " accept"]) .

```
(def x (map #(into #{} %) inp))

-> [#{Fetch, get, bring} #{Take, receive, accept}]


(map #(hash-map (gensym ":key") %) x)

-> ({:key6393 #{" bring " " get" "Fetch"}} {:key6394 #{"  Take" " receive" " accept"}})
```